# What is the difference between product = Product.new and @product in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Instance variables are used in models in rails. When we need to access data from a Table in database how do we access data using model objects by using instance variables.

Comment: Whats the difference between a instance and lexical variable? Well one belongs to an object and the other has lexical scope.

Answer (score 0):

`Product` = your Class

`Product.new` = Instance Class (object)

`product = Product.new` = assigning to the variable product `Product.new`.

`@product` is equal to product **BUT** accessible from views, helpers etc..

`@variable` is an instance variable.

`variable` is a simple variable only accessible from your method.